Mysql Innodb reads are too high on raspberry
we have got some raspberry devices running small webservers with mysql database.  They are literally clones and we are monitoring them through MySQL Workbench. Some of them has this high innodb read problem, these machines so slow they cant even serve the minimal API content which is based on database.
You can see the high value on right hand side, down below: InnoDB disk reads.
The client program is a python one.
Any idea how to get it back to normal?
I tried to change some global variables, but here are the innodb read connected ones:
innodb_encryption_threads....... 0
innodb_purge_threads............ 4
innodb_random_read_ahead........ OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold..... 56
innodb_read_io_threads.......... 4
innodb_read_only................ OFF


You haven't shown any code, SQL queries, table DDL, or optimization plans (EXPLAIN output). Anyone reading this can only make wild guesses at how to improve your situation. I could also suggest: restrict the traffic to your raspberry servers, or get more raspberry servers, or change the raspberry servers to some more powerful servers that are able to keep up with the query demands.

The usual reason for a high innodb read problem is an insufficient innodb buffer pool size. Also if significant amounts of non-indexed queries are occurring MySQL will nee to read more than it need, contributing to your high innodb read problem.

Also the amount of RAM available to MySQL.  And what leads you to say "high innodb read problem".  And, is this WordPress?
